# bat which runs command lines on several directories in a directory

Tags: batch-file

Following the suggestion by Foxidrive,
I have edited my question for clarity.

I would like to apply a list of command lines to files in all subfolders in a main folder called "Jan 1". Instead of changing folders manually by "cd", I am trying to make a batch file which applies command lines to the files in every single subfolders. What I have is 30 folders containing a bunch of files in each folder. They are data sets from 30 different participants. what I want to know is how to go into a subfoder one after the other.

My first attempt was to use "For" loop.

"C:\Users\u00854141\Documents\PES\Record2016\Jan 1".
I would like to run command A, B, and C on files in those 30 folders.

```
@ECHO OFF
CD C:\Users\u00854141\Documents\PES\Record2016\Jan 1
For /D %%g in (*) do (
    command A
    command B
    command C
)
```

As can be seen in the below, I've been getting generous help from several people. But because I didn't make myself clear, still I haven't solve the problem. Thank you everyone for your patience. 
Best regards,

Comment: What is your exact problem? please describe... and check out `for /R` (remember `for /D` matches against directories but not the files in there)...

Comment: I've got 30 subfolders in Jan 1. Each subfolders contains some files which needs to be processed with command A, B, and C. Sorry for not making myself clear. many thanks

Comment: Your subsequent remarks show that you still haven't given an accurate description of the task.  There is an `edit` feature that allows you to correct and enhance your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the command after `cmd /c`, I make it understandable for you to see what's going on.

```
@ECHO OFF

forfiles /p "C:\Users\u00854141\Documents\PES\Record2016\Jan 1" /s /c "cmd /c if @isdir == FALSE (echo FILE - DO COMMAND HERE) else (echo. & echo DIR - @path & echo.)"

pause >nul
```

Comment: sorry, but this only runs on files in \c++ directory, but not sub-directories in the \c++?. I need to apply command lines on files in each subfolders. thanks!

Comment: Oh, what an embarrassment !! I tried it out and forgot to change the directory!

Comment: well, sorry again (and thank you so much), but I'm wondering if you could help me making a batch which go through each subfolders in "Jan 1". I've got 30 subfolders in Jan 1. Each subfolders containing some files which needs to be processed with command A, B, and C. Sorry for not making myself clear.

Comment: What command is it? Because the command need to be work out in a single line like what I did in `cmd /c`

Comment: Oh, I see. I meant command A, B, and C are different commands. I need to apply a bunch of different commands one after the other. A->B->C for files in each subfolders in Jan 1. sorry again

Comment: You can use "&" sign to separate each commands. E.g. `@echo off & set string=hello & echo %string% & pause >nul` will work as expected

Answer (score 0):

Fixed code, using `for /R`:

```
@echo off
pushd .
cd /D "C:\Users\u00854141\Documents\PES\Record2016\Jan 1"
for /R %%F in (*) do (
    pushd "%%~dpF"
    rem command_A "%%~nxF"
    rem command_B "%%~nxF"
    rem command_C "%%~nxF"
    popd
)
popd
```

The `for /R` loop walks through all files in all (sub-)directories recursively.
In the loop body, `pushd` changes to the current directory temporarily before coming to the 3 commands; `popd` restores the original directory.
The `"%%~nxF"` portion in the command place-holders refers to the pure file name of the current item; if you want to pass the full path to the command, give `"%%~fF"` instead.

Comment: many thanks, aschipfl. It works well for my purpose, but only problem is that it keeps doing the same thing. For instance, if the command A is "mkdir hope", it creates a folder called "hope" in each folder then tries to repeat this "mkdir hope" command because the screen shows a rows of "file hope already exists" message.

Comment: That's because `for /R` loops through _every file_, so if there are 30 files in each directory, `mkdir` tries to create the `hope` directory 30 times; in other words, `mkdir` is _not_ a command on _each file_ like you posted in your question; for executing the command sequence _for each directory_ you need to use `for /R /D` to walk through the directories rather than the individual files...